# Locking mechanism for ms access database from java client application for multiple table update

Tags: java, ms-access

I have a ms access database and mutliple users (3-4 users) work on it through java based client application over intranet. I have following schema in database:

1. tblCustomer: Contains account static info of a customer. Fields are:

   a) CustomerID 
   b) CustomerIDRevisionNo ( if change in some static information of customer
     happen) 
   c) other static information fields of customer.
2. tblOrder : Fields are 
   a) OrderID
   b)  CustomerID 
   c) CustomerIDRevisionNo
3. tblOrderData: Contains all data for a particular OrderID.

OrderID is serially increasing number as orders are placed by various customers. In order to place an order, following steps are involved:
a. Revise CustomerIDRevisionNo  if some customer information changed.
b. Read tblOrder to find current max OrderID and  insert new row with next OrderID.
C.  Insert data for new OrderID in tblOrderData.

Now how should I set lock or transaction isolation level from java client application for this process. It is to be noted that if some error happens, then roll back should revert the whole process.

Answer (score 2):

As always, look at [documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/jdbc/basics/transactions.html):

> The way to allow two or more statements to be grouped into a
>   transaction is to disable the auto-commit mode. This is demonstrated
>   in the following code, where con is an active connection:
>
> `con.setAutoCommit(false);`

Then you do your steps for placing an order, and when you're done, you call `commit` method of `Connection` class:

`con.commit()`

Additionaly you may want to wrap your code with `try...catch` clause catching `SQLException` exception. That's basically how you ensure that if something goes wrong you won't corrupt the database.

**P.S.**
I assume you're using JDBC driver.

Comment: Yes I am current doing like this only. A summary is this: a) con = DriverManager.getConnection(url); b) con.setAutoCommit (false) c) con.setTransactionIsolation(TRANSACTION_READ_COMMITTED); d) perform all steps  e) if everything fine, and no exception, con.commit otherwise con.rollback.

Comment: Problem is when multiple users are working, often when one user goes for actual commit, the database finds that 
OrderID has already increased by one in meantime. I am able to rollback changes in such scenario but 
how can I ensure that only one user enters into this part of code at a time.

Comment: Did you try to omit `setTransactionIsolation` call?

Comment: @Sandeep, by default MS Access uses record-leveling locking. The first user to edit a record maintains exclusive access to it. Should you rollback, the auto-increment ID may be used and next record ID begins after. It sounds like you care about the consecutive order of primary key. You should not worry as such IDs will jump around due to deletion/compact & repair/bulk append. More, you should never use PKs or FKs in any of your application as they maintain tables' relational referential integrity. Consider using a separate row number field that your app (not db) increments with new record.